# QueryDSL usage with different relational databases

Tags: java, rdbms, querydsl

I have an application which may work with different type of databases(relational dbs). Now it uses hibernate to connect and work with them and for different databases we must use different drivers and write code for each db.
Is it possible with QueryDSL to write unique code for multiple relational databases(all of them have same schemas, tables and field names)? Or any suggestions in order to make my code independent of database type? Any analogues of QueryDSL?
And can I find good tutorials on QueryDSL theme?